# Problem with NOLOCK on SQL 2008 using a temporary table and select statements

Tags: sql-server-2008, nolock

I am using SQL 2008 and I am getting an error most of the time I run a stored procedure. There error is: `could not continue scan with nolock due to data movement`. I have looked online for this and it seems that most people get this when updating their SQL version or when doing updates/deletes. I am not doing either. Also the solution seems to be to remove the NOLOCK yet I am not using NOLOCK (unless it is default in SQL Server 2008). I have also tried to insert `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ uncommitted` yet it hasn't made any changes.

My stored procedure consists of getting parameters, creating a temporary table, filling the table with SELECT statements only and then fetching information from the table.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Adding the stored procedure code might help.

Comment: Kyra: can you post a code sample for us to look at?

Comment: First time when it's not my bug :)))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a patch for that in SQL server 2008: [FIX: You receive error 605 and error 824 when you run a query that inserts data into a temporary table in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960770/nl)

(fixed link. oops)